Punctuation for "the following" followed by sentence
How do I separate "construction" and "let" in the following sentence? (the context comes from mathematics)
More examples come from the following construction. Let A be ...
Thank you in advance

Is it important to capitalize "Let"? You could use quotation marks or a block quote.

@StuartF, those wouldn’t be common in mathematical text.

I shall vote to leave this question open because it may be easily recast as: "More examples come from the following proposition". It is reasonable to equate construction (of an argument or line of reasoning) with a proposition. That being the case, all that is needed is the usual mathematical convention of the full stop as shown in the question.

Either a period or a colon would be okay. There might be a slight preference for the colon.
As a side note, in mathematical text, names of variables are always set in italics (or, depending on their meaning, in bold). Thus your truncated sentence should read, “Let A be…”

:-  I do not think that a comma would be the standard punctuation.  The separation between the two clauses is too substantial.  It should be either a colon or a full stop.  In many or even most texts of this kind, however, you might find a colon followed by a dash (:-) with the example on a separate line.

Jeez, @Tuffy, I don’t know how many times I’ve looked at that sentence, and yet I never noticed I’d used the wrong word. It’s now fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.
